# How to check if a QThread is alive or killed and restart it if it is killed in PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have an PyQt5 application to update database collections one by one using QThread and send updation signal to main thread as each collection gets updated to reflect it on GUI. It runs continuously 24X7. But somehow the data stops getting updated and also GUI stops getting signals. But the application is still running as other part are accessible and functioning properly. Also no errors are found in log file.
Mostly the application runs fine but after some random period this problem arises(first time after approximately a month, then after 2 weeks and now after 23 days). However restarting the application solves the problem.
I tried using isRunning() method and isFinished() method but no change found.

Can anyone tell what is the problem?? Thank you in advance.
Also tell how to check weather the QThread is stuck or killed?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your question is very generic and a quick search on Google and Stackoverflow yields a lot of results asking the same question. Search query on google e.g. "qthread check if thread is running".  

And we can't tell what the problem is why your thread is killed without any code, logs and traceback errors.

Answer (score 0):

If any exception occur in the thread, then thread can be finished soon.
so You should use settimeout function to calling any third party library(data update) in the thread.
That will solve your problem.